# How to fit a function for different groups in a data set using R

Tags: r

Please, how can I fit a function for different groups in a data set (Soil) using R. the first column is the group i.e. Plot and the second column is the observed variable i.e. Depth

```
Plot Depth
1 12.5
1 14.5
1 15.8
1 16.1
1 18.9
1 21.2
1 23.4
1 25.7
2 13.1
2 15.0
2 15.8
2 16.3
2 17.4
2 18.6
2 22.6
2 24.1
2 25.6
3 11.5
3 12.2
3 13.9
3 14.7
3 18.9
3 20.5
3 21.6
3 22.6
3 24.1
3 25.8
4 10.2
4 21.5
4 15.1
4 12.3
4 10.0
4 13.5
4 16.5
4 19.2
4 17.6
4 14.1
4 19.7
```

I used the 'for' statement but only saw output for Plot 1.
This was how I applied the 'for' statement:

After importing my data in R, I saved it as: SNq,

```
for (i in 1:SNq$Plot[i]) {
    dp <- SNq$Depth[SNq$Plot==SNq$Plot[i]]
    fit1 = fitdist(dp, "gamma") ## this is the function I'm fitting. The function is not the issue. My challenge is the 'for' statement.
    fit1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work. Just make one change in your code:

**Why would it work ?**

**Because:** unique function will return unique values `(1,2,3)` which are nothing but the groups in `Plot` column. With unique value, we can subset the data using `SNq$Depth[SNq$Plot==i]` and get depth value for that group.

```
for (i in unique(SNq$Plot)) { # <- here
    dp <- SNq$Depth[SNq$Plot==i]
    fit1 = fitdist(dp, "gamma") ## this is the function I'm fitting. The function is not the issue. My challenge is the 'for' statement.
    plot(fit1)
}
```

Comment: I think you have a mistake here in line 1 `SNq$Plot]` the bracket will cause an error. Can you maybe explain in one sentence what the difference is. Or why you made the change?

Comment: Sorry my bad! It's corrected now. Let me explain that too.

Comment: The same result. Only result for plot 1

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` suggestion:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("fitdistrplus")

fits <- SNq %>%
  group_by(Plot) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fits = map(data, ~ fitdist(data = .$Depth, distr = "gamma")),
         summaries = map(fit, summary))
```

You could continue with `print(fits$fits)` and `print(fits$summaries)` to access the different fits and their summary. Alternatively you can use a syntax like `fits$fits[[1]]` and `fits$summaries[[1]]` to access them.

Comment: Sorry to hear. You could try with `~ fitdist(data = Depth, distr = "gamma")` or `~ fitdist(data = .$Depth, distr = "gamma")` inside the `map()` function.

Comment: I'm aware of this code. But is there away to run such function for all plots at once?

Comment: The `mutate()` function in my answer runs the `fitdist()` function for all plots at once, resulting in a model fit for each plot. I've updated my original answer with some clarification,

Comment: Supertasty, please is it possible to coerce the result into dataframe. Let say coercing the parameter estimates by Plot into dataframe

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(SNq)) {
  dp <- SNq$Depth[SNq$Plot==SNq$Plot[i]]
  fit1 = fitdist(dp, "gamma")
  fit1
}
```

Comment: The modifications didn't work. Brought result for just Plot 1.